# Hidden/Shown AsyncFileUpload Control Doesn't Fire Server-Side UploadedComplete Event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I recently came across the AsyncFileUpload control in the latest (3.0.40412) release of the ASP.Net Ajax Control Toolkit. There appears to be an issue when using it in a hidden control that is later revealed, such as a `<div>` tag with `visible=false`.

**Example:**

Page code -

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act" %>
.
.
.
<act:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlFileUpload">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowUpload" Text="Show Upload" />
        <div runat="server" id="divUpload" visible="false">
            <act:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" id="ctlFileUpload" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server-side Code -

```
Protected Sub ctlFileUpload_UploadedComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles ctlFileUpload.UploadedComplete

End Sub

Protected Sub btnShowUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowUpload.Click
    divUpload.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I have a breakpoint on the UploadedComplete event but it never fires. However, if you take the AsyncFileUpload control out of the `<div>`, making it visible at initial page render, the control works as expected.

So, is this a bug within the AsynchUploadControl, or am I not grasping a fundamental concept (which happens regularly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your  tag has the following attribuytes - **enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"**  Secondly, you have to have the AsyncFileUpload in an invisible DIV within a visible DIV.  See these two threads on it.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1489399.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1479689.aspx?PageIndex=2

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. It appears to have solved the problem.

Second, you're a better searcher than I am. I spent several hours yesterday looking for this, including on the asp.net site, and came up empty. Nice work.

Finally, what a kludge. I hope the Ajax Control Toolkit guys give this one some attention for the next release.

Comment: Adding this to the form element was enough to get it working for me: enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post". I am also not hiding the AsyncFileUpload control itself but a panel that is around the upload control.