# How to use form with method="post" in asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I am using ajax toolkit asyncFileUpload control

I had problem that my server side events does not fired and found this posts [Hidden/Shown AsyncFileUpload Control Doesn't Fire Server-Side UploadedComplete Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917030/hidden-shown-asyncfileupload-control-doesnt-fire-server-side-uploadedcomplete-e)

I inserted my uploader inside form and with this attributes `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"`

This uploader is inside my webs form which is inside master page

After adding this attributes i got this error

```
    A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:
```

And here is my web form

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <form id="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="target_url"
    runat="server">
    <div id="Div1" runat="server">
        Just some time to make sure that the page doesn't get reloaded after uploading:
        <%=DateTime.Now %><br />
        <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="FileUpload_UploadCompleted"
            OnClientUploadComplete="FileUpload_ClientUploadCompleted" OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
            OnLoad="FileUpload_OnLoad" />
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgUpload" src="" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblerror" Text="" />
    </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This is one of the major reasons why ASP .NET WebForms **sucks**.

Comment: The solution is to jam your whole page into the **one** `form` tag you're allowed and then post the whole damn thing every single time. GL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MasterPage` already has a `form` element. Nested `form`s aren't allowed...

I don't know much about the `ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload` but, since it is a server control, it should change the parent `form`s properties. Have you tried removing the form like the code below?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div id="Div1" runat="server">
        Just some time to make sure that the page doesn't get reloaded after uploading:
        <%=DateTime.Now %><br />
        <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="FileUpload_UploadCompleted"
            OnClientUploadComplete="FileUpload_ClientUploadCompleted" OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
            OnLoad="FileUpload_OnLoad" />
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgUpload" src="" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblerror" Text="" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

***Another Possible Solution:***

"Pop" a "modal" `form` that just contains your form with the `file upload control`. This will remedy the nested forms issue. But, it does changed the functionality.

Comment: Yes i know that only one form tag is allowed but how i can make uploader to work?

Comment: Yes but without form tags server side events does not firing

Comment: does your `MasterPage` have a `form`?

Answer (score 1):

As a very dirty hack try adding adding a `<form></form>` in front of your form, and take the runat="server" out of your nested form.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    **<form></form>**
    <form id="Form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="target_url"
    >
    <div id="Div1" runat="server">
        Just some time to make sure that the page doesn't get reloaded after uploading:
        <%=DateTime.Now %><br />
        <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="FileUpload_UploadCompleted"
            OnClientUploadComplete="FileUpload_ClientUploadCompleted" OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
            OnLoad="FileUpload_OnLoad" />
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgUpload" src="" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblerror" Text="" />
    </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

In the past this has worked for me - when forced to work with WebForms.  I don't know why but I find that quite a lot with WebForms.

You really should switch to MVC if you want to write code like this however.  Even if this does work it's not what I'd call a solution.  WebForms just isn't designed to do this.